# Issue referencing temporary unsaved workbook - runtime Error 438

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue being able to run the macro on a temporary workbook, this is the faulty line:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "FilePath;", _
        Destination:=temp.Range("$A$1"))
```

This piece of code shows with runtime error. I tried other techniques such as readOnly but they did not work either.

Is there any solution for this problem?

```
Sub temp()

Dim Qa As Workbook
Dim temp As Workbook
Dim sum As Worksheet
Dim cov As Worksheet
'Dim ClientDate1 As Date
'Dim ClientDate2 As Date
'Dim Url As String
'Dim FilePath As String

Set Qa = ThisWorkbook
Set temp = Workbooks.Add
Set sum = Qa.Worksheets("Summary")
Set cov = Qa.Worksheets("Coverage")
ClientName = sum.Range("A1")
ClientDate = sum.Range("A3").Value
ClientDate1 = Format(ClientDate, "mm")
ClientDate2 = Format(ClientDate, "yyyy")

Url = "http://" & "wiki.rosslyn.local/mediawiki/index.php/"
FilePath = Url & ClientName & "_" & ClientDate2 & "_" & ClientDate1

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "FilePath;", _
        Destination:=temp.Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "Deloitte_2013_08"
        .CommandType = 0
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With

  temp.Close

    End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this piece of your code correct: `With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=FilePath & ";", _`, and so on...

Comment: @KazJaw nope it doesn't work for some reason and it comes with runtime error 438.

Comment: The address is saved on a local server, any idea how to get it to work? @KazJaw

Comment: `QueryTables` are unstable type of object. Therefore I don't use it always where it's possible. Consider switching to `ADO`

Comment: @KazJaw what is a ADO method, I've never used this method before and I am not used to it

Comment: [this is entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for you to read.

Comment: @KazJaw Thanks I've manages to solve the problem, it couldn't understand Filepath because it was reading it as a string.

Comment: ...what I pointed out in my first comment but rather not clearly enough. Anyway, good you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy [James Cone](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df71afb1-d0c1-4bc5-915c-2aca065096b9/runtime-error-438-helppp):

> Remove the quotation marks from around ClientName.
>
> From...
>
> ```
>  "Url" & "ClientName" &
> ```
>
> To...
>
> ```
>  "Url" & ClientName &  
> '---
> ```